# need value without {} breses from spinner control

Tags: android

I have spinner control where I add string array so I get all item in the spinner and when I print selected item into toast that also prints with string array name=item between {} braces
I get only item name to insert in `SQLite`

```
String[] question = {"How are you?","Where are you?","Who are you?"};
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String str = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ans: "+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
}
```

Comment: Share you adapter code also and the arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Use String.split("=") to split the toString() result.